# Function with both varying number of parameters (*args) and parameter with default value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, variadic-functions, default-value

I am using Python 3.6.0

Consider the following code:

```
def foo(a, b='default-value', *args):
    print('first argument=' + a)
    print('default-value argument=' + b)
    print('rest of arguments: ')
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

The following function call:

```
foo('arg1','arg2','arg3','arg4')
```

results with:

```
first argument=arg1
default-value argument=arg2
rest of arguments: 
arg3
arg4
```

But I expected:

```
first argument=arg1
default-value argument=default-value
rest of arguments:
arg2
arg3
arg4
```

Is it possible to create a function that accepts both varying number of parameters and a parameter with default value in Python? How can I achieve a result that I am expecting as outlined above?

Comment: Given your logic… how exactly do you expect to be able to pass any value for `b`, if you seem to expect it to be skipped because it already has a value?

Comment: I thought that in that case I would just pass it explicitly like: `foo('arg1',b='something','arg2','arg3')`

Answer (score 1):

In **Python 3**, you can move that keyword argument after `*args` in the function definition, so only the positionals are captured by `*args`:

```
def foo(a, *args,  b='default-value'):
    ...
```

---

```
first argument=arg1
default-value argument=default-value
rest of arguments: 
arg2
arg3
arg4
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How would I approach this if I also want to use `**kwargs`? Eg. the following signature is not allowed: `def foo(a, *args, **kwargs, b='default-value')`

Comment: @GrzegorzŚwirski Once you have `kwargs` in there, you don't need to set a default value for `b`. Just do `kwargs.get('b', 'default-value')` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can archive what you want by putting the parameters taht have a defalt value as last on the params

```
def foo(a, *args, b='default-value'):
    print('first argument=' + a)
    print('default-value argument=' + b)
    print('rest of arguments: ')
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

foo('arg1','arg2','arg3','arg4')
```

Result:

```
first argument=arg1
default-value argument=default-value
rest of arguments: 
arg2
arg3
arg4
```